# PHP: cannot pass single quoted string to mysqli query

Tags: php

I was fighting for hours with this simply thing:

```
$var=var;    
$result = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM $db WHERE column3 = '$var' ";
```

The error I get is: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'var\'' at line 1

Names are correct, it works in mysql query. Think I tried all possible quoting options, what is wrong?

UPDATE: as requested I used the escaping, but error remains the same

```
$var=var;   
$var = $conn->real_escape_string($var);
$result = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM {$db} WHERE column3 = '{$var}' ";
```

Comment: You're missing quotes around `var`. Is that intentional?

Comment: You mean in the first line? Then it is.

Comment: So, `var` is a constant? If you're trying to store a string, then you'll need quotes around it.

Comment: For now it is constant. I change it to $var="var";  same error.

Comment: It's impossible that `$var="var";` produces the text `\'var\'` in the error message. Where do those `\'` come from?

Answer (score 0):

There must be

```
$var = $mysqli->real_escape_string($var);
$sql = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM {$db} WHERE column3 = '{$var}' ";
```

Instead of:

```
$result = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM $db WHERE column3 = '$var' ";
$result = $mysqli->real_escape_string($result) ; //Totally wrong.
```

Comment: gives me Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in ...

Comment: So `$mysqli` isn't an object of a `mysqli` object?

Comment: I have no idea, are there some prerequisites?

Answer (score 0):

I tested in mysql console with a bad SQL query:

```
 mysql>  SELECT column1, column2 FROM WHERE column3 = 'varvalue';
```

It gives this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE column3 = 'varvalue'' at line 1
```

In fact the table name is missing. I guess that your variable $db could be null/empty/unset.

Please try :

```
$db = "mytable";
$var = "varvalue";
$result = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM $db WHERE column3 = '$var' ";
```

Comment: No, query without the WHERE filter works

Comment: I've no better idea then asking you for echoing $result SQL string before MySQL query ?

Comment: The echo is as expected