# PHP: cannot pass single quoted string to mysqli query round 2

Tags: php, mysqli

Yesterday I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210348/php-cannot-pass-single-quoted-string-to-mysqli-query) and got misdirected answers. Now with escape in place, I hope we can get to the issue.

```
$var="var";   
$var = $conn->real_escape_string($var);
$result = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM {$db} WHERE column3 = '{$var}' ";
```

Returns:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'var\'' at line 1

Note that the query works properly in database itself and only the WHERE clause is causing issues in php.

Comment: Can you please echo your query and paste it here?

Comment: can you put the result of `echo $result;` in your qusetion?

Comment: SELECT column1, column2 FROM database WHERE column3 = 'var'

Comment: Escaping every single input variable is so annoying. Why don't you just use prepared statements?

Comment: Does adding a closing semicolon (`;`) to the query make a difference?

Comment: what is type of `column3`? int or varchar?

Comment: are the single quotes really single quotes?

Comment: @Marek - what you mean than that?

Comment: Yes, I did even copy them from web texts and pasted to my file, still the same. Could it be some encoding problem?

Comment: adding the semicolon did not help, all columns are varchar

Comment: it is not answers are misdirecting but your questions are

Comment: @imsiso there are also utf8 single quotes, which look similar.

Comment: _“Yesterday I posted a question and got misdirected answers.”_ – you did not _understand_ the answers (/comments), because you lack very basic knowledge … that would be closer to the truth.

Comment: @user2851828 - Can you please *edit* the question (not post a comment) and post the *real* SQL query? You can use `var_dump($result);` to obtain it. `SELECT column1, column2 FROM database WHERE column3 = 'var'` will trigger a *different* SQL error because `database` is a reserved keyword. As it's now, there's no way to answer it: syntax errors are 100% bound to actual code.

Comment: Make sure the collation and charset for the db/table are corrrct for php. Apparently collation is a big gotcha.

Comment: I wasn't aware such simple query requires advanced knowledge. Of course the database name is different.